# Sorting a list of dictionaries based on a key

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which contains student data
It is something like

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> students = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> std1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
std1["name"] = "sai";
std1["age"] = 22;
std1["gender"] = "male";
students.Add(std1);

Dictionary<string, object> std2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
std2["name"] = "Julia";
std2["gender"] = "female";
students.Add(std2);

Dictionary<string, object> std3 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
std3 ["name"] = "sunny";
std3 ["age"] = 23;
students.Add(std3);
```

And I want to sort the list of students based on either `name`, `age` or `gender`, I am trying something like this:

```
var ordered = students.OrderBy(x => x["name"]);
```

If I try with either `age` or `gender` it is returning an error that key is not found, as `std2` doesn't have `age` and `std3` doesn't have `gender`.

I need all the records even it doesn't contain the value for sorted key, Any way to solve this problem, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using a dictionary instead of a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort by a key that is not present in all of the dictionaries, you'll need  to return a default value instead, for example 0.

```
var ordered = students.OrderBy(dict =>
{
    string name;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue("name", out name))
        return "";
    return name;
});
```

Shorter version using the conditional ternary operator:

```
var ordered = students.OrderBy(dict =>
{
    string name;
    return dict.TryGetValue("name", out name) ? name : 0;
});
```

I use [`Dictionary.TryGetValue(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns a bool depicting whether the key was found in the dictionary and its value returned.

Comment: Awesome :) +1 for explanation on TryGetValue

Answer (score 3):

It is better to create a class like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
List<YourClass> students = new List<YourClass>();
YourClass std1 = new YourClass();
std1.Name = "sai";
std1.Age = 22;
std1.Gender = "male";
students.Add(std1);

yourClass std2 = new yourClass();
std2.Name = "Julia";
std2.Gender = "female";
students.Add(std2);

yourClass std3 = new yourClass();
std3.Name = "sunny";
std3.Age = 23;
students.Add(std3);

var ordered = students.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

This arrangement stores the same data you had in multiple dictionaries. However, it's far more clear and understandable.

Comment: Thanks :), It helped me

Comment: @satishkumarV This is definitely the solution you should go for unless you **have to** use dictionaries.

Comment: Yea, I agree with you, but the thing is dictionary may contain any data and any no of keys, Sometimes it may contain student data, some other time employee and Address for in another time, I can't create 100's or 1000's of classes, anyhow if the list of keys are constant and fixed this solution might be awesome :) and thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you also have to represent employees data somehow, it's a classical case for inheritance. Using dictionaries for this type of problem is extremely discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by supplying a `GetOptional` method that returns some default object in situations when the dictionary does not have a specific key:

```
V GetOptional<K,V>(IDictionary<K,V> d, K key, V absent) {
    V res;
    return d.TryGetValue(key, out res) ? res : absent;
}
```

Now you can sort like this:

```
var byName = students.OrderBy(x => GetOptional<string,object>(x, "name", "----"));
var byAge = students.OrderBy(x => GetOptional<string,object>(x, "age", "10000"));
```

**Note:** Using dictionaries like this gives you flexibility at the expense of clarity. It is usually better to define a special `Student` type, rather than using a universal collection of key-value pairs.

Comment: Thanks :), It helped me