# Linking two Lists of different types to a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to make a `ListView` display both an Image and the name of the Image Selected. So far I have successfully bound a `List<BitmapImage>` to the ListView.ItemsSource that displays both the `Image` element along with a `Textblock` element inside a `ItemTemplate`, I have also successfully added the name of each `Image` to a separate `List<string>`. Now this is where I am stuck, How can I bind both the `List<BitmapImage>` and `List<string>` to the single ListView and therefore each List Item's respected field.

Code snippets are given below:

XAML ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView_ViewPhotos" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--Image Column-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <!--Name Column-->
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageList}" Height="100" Width="150" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Listimg_Caption" Foreground="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Height="40" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding ImageName}" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#

```
public  List<string> ImageName = new List<string>();
private async void appBar_GetFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filelist = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in filelist)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string FileName = file.Name;
            //var imageData = await activeFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            //var imageData = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage;
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            }
            ImageName.Add(FileName);
            ImageList.Add(bitmapImage);
        }
        else break;
    }
    listView_ViewPhotos.ItemsSource = null;
    listView_ViewPhotos.ItemsSource = ???;

    gridView_ViewPhotos.ItemsSource = null;
    gridView_ViewPhotos.ItemsSource = ???;
```

Comment: You need to create a class with two properties (`Image` and `ImageName`). Then a List of class instead of two separate `List` and finally set the `ItemsSource` to the `List`. Example of how to create a class and a `List` of it http://stackoverflow.com/a/32285112/2946329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 2 lists, just use 1:

1st, Create a new class, let's call it `ImageDetails`.
This class contains 2 properties, 1 is the image itself, 1 is the Image's name

```
public class ImageDetails
{
    public BitmapImage Image{get;set:}
    public string ImageName{get;set;}
}
```

So now, you instead of loading 2 lists, just call `List<ImageDetails>`

**Example for Add:**

```
List<ImageDetails> list = new List<ImageDetails>();
ImageDetails _imgDetails = new ImageDetails();
_imgDetails.Image = bitmapImage;
_imgDetails.ImageName = FileName;
list.Add(_imgDetails);
```

**Example for GetAll:**

```
foreach(var img in list)
{
    var image = img.Image; //this is your BitmapImage
    var name = img.ImageName; //this is your image Name
    //other work
}
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I hoped! I did originally have a ImageDetails class similar to the one that you outlined, but I abandoned it as i thought it was a dead end. Turns out I was wrong, Thank you!

Comment: @Haybale100 Glad that it helps you :)